# I hope to add masked area target detection to the CrowdCounting-P2PNet source code

Tags: python-3.x, image, face-detection

This is the source code of dense crowd recognition on github: https://github.com/TencentYoutuResearch/CrowdCounting-P2PNet. I hope to add a specific area mask to the detect.py file of this source code to realize the number of people in a specific area. identify

When I imported the image, I tried to select five points to form an area around the image, and then detected it, but the program reported an error when running.

import argparse
import datetime
import random
import time
from pathlib import Path

import torch
import torchvision.transforms as standard_transforms
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
import cv2
from crowd_datasets import build_dataset
from engine import *
from models import build_model
import os
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def get_args_parser():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Set parameters for P2PNet evaluation', add_help=False)

```
# * Backbone
parser.add_argument('--backbone', default='vgg16_bn', type=str,
                    help="name of the convolutional backbone to use")

parser.add_argument('--row', default=2, type=int,
                    help="row number of anchor points")
parser.add_argument('--line', default=2, type=int,
                    help="line number of anchor points")

parser.add_argument('--output_dir', default='',
                    help='path where to save')
parser.add_argument('--weight_path', default='',
                    help='path where the trained weights saved')

parser.add_argument('--gpu_id', default=0, type=int, help='the gpu used for evaluation')

return parser
```

def main(args, debug=False):

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '{}'.format(args.gpu_id)

print(args)
device = torch.device('cuda')
# get the P2PNet
model = build_model(args)
# move to GPU
model.to(device)
# load trained model
if args.weight_path is not None:
    checkpoint = torch.load(args.weight_path, map_location='cpu')
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
# convert to eval mode
model.eval()
# create the pre-processing transform
transform = standard_transforms.Compose([
    standard_transforms.ToTensor(), 
    standard_transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

hl1 = 203 / 907  # 监测区域高度距离图片顶部比例
wl1 = 303 / 1603  # 监测区域高度距离图片左部比例
hl2 = 81 / 907  # 监测区域高度距离图片顶部比例
wl2 = 872 / 1603  # 监测区域高度距离图片左部比例
hl3 = 415 / 907  # 监测区域高度距离图片顶部比例
wl3 = 1037 / 1603  # 监测区域高度距离图片左部比例
hl4 = 704 / 907  # 监测区域高度距离图片顶部比例
wl4 = 770 / 1603  # 监测区域高度距离图片左部比例
hl5 = 685 / 907  # 监测区域高度距离图片顶部比例
wl5 = 307 / 1603  # 监测区域高度距离图片左部比例

# set your image path here
img_paths = r"E:\vedio\test"
output_dir = r"E:\vedio\test"
for img in os.listdir(img_paths):
    img_path = img_paths+"/"+img
    print(f"{img_path}开始识别")
    # load the images
    img_raw = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
    # round the size
    width, height = img_raw.size
    new_width = width // 128 * 128
    new_height = height // 128 * 128
    img_raw = img_raw.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # pre-processing
    im0 = transform(img_raw)

    mask = np.zeros([im0.shape[1], im0.shape[2]], dtype=np.uint8)
    # mask[round(img.shape[1] * hl1):img.shape[1], round(img.shape[2] * wl1):img.shape[2]] = 255
    pts = np.array([[int(im0.shape[2] * wl1), int(im0.shape[1] * hl1)],  # pts1
                    [int(im0.shape[2] * wl2), int(im0.shape[1] * hl2)],  # pts2
                    [int(im0.shape[2] * wl3), int(im0.shape[1] * hl3)],  # pts3
                    [int(im0.shape[2] * wl4), int(im0.shape[1] * hl4)],  # pts4
                    [int(im0.shape[2] * wl5), int(im0.shape[1] * hl5)]], np.int32)
    mask = cv2.fillPoly(mask, [pts], (255, 255, 255))
    print(mask)
    img = im0.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    img = cv2.add(img, np.zeros(np.shape(img), dtype=np.uint8), mask=mask)
    img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    cv2.polylines(im0, [pts], True, (255, 255, 0), 3)

    print(img)
    samples = torch.Tensor(img).unsqueeze(0)
    samples = samples.to(device)

    # run inference
    outputs = model(samples)
    outputs_scores = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs['pred_logits'], -1)[:, :, 1][0]

    outputs_points = outputs['pred_points'][0]

    threshold = 0.5
    # filter the predictions
    points = outputs_points[outputs_scores > threshold].detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
    predict_cnt = int((outputs_scores > threshold).sum())

    outputs_scores = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs['pred_logits'], -1)[:, :, 1][0]

    outputs_points = outputs['pred_points'][0]
    # draw the predictions
    size = 2
    img_to_draw = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img_raw), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    for p in points:
        img_to_draw = cv2.circle(img_to_draw, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), size, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    # save the visualized image
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_dir, '{}-pred{}.jpg'.format(img_path.split(".")[0],predict_cnt)), img_to_draw)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('P2PNet evaluation script', parents=[get_args_parser()])
args = parser.parse_args()
main(args)

Comment: Please post the source code in the text instead of a picture. It will also be helpful to paste the error content.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)